# When a user clicks on a Google Ad, hide the referrer from the landing page

Tags: google, google-search, google-ads, search

I am doing Google Search Ads, after a customers click on my ads they will get forwarded to an affiliate page. Now, I don't want these affiliate networks to know from where my customer came (had bad experience with networks stealing my customers by copying my exact funnel). So the referrer of `google.com` should be completely inaccessible.

Also during this process there shouldn't be any lost customers. Everything should stay consistent without any clicks not tracked.

Comment: Unless Google Ads supports this as a feature, my guess is that it isn't possible.